# How can I find the observation that better suit my pattern?

Tags: r, stringr

I am using str_which in order to find city names in strings, but some city names are inclued in another ones. For example: "beautiful city" is included in "cool beautiful city", but they are different cities.

So, I want my code to provide something like:

```
df <- data.frame(city = c("beautiful city", "cool beautiful city", "strange local", "noname local"))

pattern <- c("cool beautiful city", "name local", "noname local", "beautiful city")

function_like_str_which (df[1], pattern)

> [4], [1]

function_like_str_which (df[4], pattern)

> [3], [2]
```

The `str_which()` provides me something like this, but not in the "most suitable match" order. It is like:

```
str_which (df[1], pattern)

> [1], [4]

str_which (df[4], pattern)

> [2], [3]
```

Can someone help me? :)

Thank you!

The `str_which` function doesn't provide me the most suitable matches.

Comment: You may need `str_locate`.  I guess your input is not syntactically correct i.e. `df <- data.frame (city = c("beautiful city", "cool beautiful city", "strange local", "noname local"))`?  Then using `match` i.e. `match(df$city[1], pattern)#
[1] 4;
> match(df$city[4], pattern)#
[1] 3`

Comment: The str _locate gives me the exact same output of str_which, it doesn't find the better matches.

Comment: Please check the updated comment.  I mentioned `match`

Comment: And you are right, the right sintax is df <- data.frame (city = c("beautiful city", "cool beautiful city", "strange local", "noname local"))

Comment: Ok! I'm back in a while to tell you :)

Answer (score 2):

We could use `agrep`

```
 which(lengths(lapply(pattern, \(x) agrep(x, df$city[1],
       max.distance = 0.5))) > 0)
[1] 1 4
 which(lengths(lapply(pattern, \(x) agrep(x, df$city[4], 
        max.distance = 0.5))) > 0)
[1] 2 3
```